# Xamarin MVVM Light ViewModelLocator setting BindingContext in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin

I would like to set up BindingContext through xaml instead of back end code. Currently I am assigning like this:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = App.Locator.Main;
    }
}
```

How can I assing BindingContext via Xaml? I tried like this:

**LoginPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Codesign.DtpMobilePortable.Views.LoginPage" BindingContext="{Binding LoginPage, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}"> 
  <StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="50" VerticalOptions="Center">

    <Entry x:Name = "EntryUsername" Text="{Binding EntryUsernameText}" Placeholder = "Username"/>  
    <Entry x:Name = "EntryPassword" Text="{Binding EntryPasswordText}" Placeholder = "Password" IsPassword = "true"   />

    <Button x:Name = "ButtonLogin"
                        Text = "{Binding LoginButtonText}"
                        TextColor = "White"
                        BackgroundColor = "{Binding LoginButtonColor}" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"/>    
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**App.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Codesign.DtpMobilePortable.ViewModels;assembly=Codesign.DtpMobilePortable"
             x:Class="Codesign.DtpMobilePortable.Views.App">
<Application.Resources>
    <viewModels:ViewModelLocator
        x:Key="ViewModelLocator" />
</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

But I get error about StaticResource doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You shall define the `StaticResources` name space on you page header .

somthing like that :

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Codesign.DtpMobilePortable;assembly=Codesign.DtpMobilePortable"
         xmlns:Vm="clr-namespace:Codesign.DtpMobilePortable.ViewModel;assembly=Codesign.DtpMobilePortable"
         x:Class="Codesign.DtpMobilePortable.Views.LoginPage"
         BindingContext="{Binding LoginPage, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}"
```

where in my sample code my `StaticResources` are defined on the `xmlnss:local` namespace above.